# Mail sent, from PHP script,not showing up

Tags: ubuntu, email, php, aws

I am running a website on two AWS EC2 instances running Ubuntu.  I am using LAMP. 
 The following PHP code used to successfully send emails, to warn of suspicious activity, but stopped doing so in January 2020.

```
<?php
    // Function to email notification of suspicious entry
    function emailPossibleSQLInjectionNotification($ipAddress, $emailAddress, $field, $entry, $time)
    {
            $to = "otagoHarbour@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Suspicious activity";
            $message = "Dear Sir,\n\n" .
                    "The following invalid entry was entered for " . $field . ".\n\n" .
                    $field . ": " .  $entry . "\n" .
                    "Client IP address" . ": " .  $ipAddress . "\n" .
                    "Client email address" . ": " .  $emailAddress . "\n" .
                    "Time" . ": " .  $time . "\n\n" .
                    "Have a wonderful day!\nWeb Site Name.\n";
            $from = "websiteSiteName@websiteSiteName.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

The following

```
cat /var/log/mail.log
```

returns

```
Mar  5 00:30:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30561]: 02339OqL008906: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+21:21:17, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=19290583, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 00:39:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sendmail[30620]: 0250d12h030620: from=root, size=550, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202003050039.0250d12h030620@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=root@localhost
Mar  5 00:39:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30621]: 0250d14c030621: from=<root@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, size=848, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202003050039.0250d12h030620@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, bodytype=7BIT, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar  5 00:39:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sendmail[30620]: 0250d12h030620: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30550, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (0250d14c030621 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar  5 00:39:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30622]: 0250d14c030621: to=<root@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, ctladdr=<root@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31084, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
 Mar  5 00:40:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30576]: 023MRjPq024050: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+02:12:56, xdelay=00:10:36, mailer=esmtp, pri=7140592, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [172.217.218.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 00:40:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30576]: 023H1exj022946: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+07:39:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=9660592, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 00:40:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30576]: 02339OqL008906: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+21:31:17, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=19380583, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 00:50:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30646]: 024KKwfi029723: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=04:29:43, xdelay=00:10:36, mailer=esmtp, pri=1290584, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [172.217.218.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 00:50:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30646]: 023H1exj022946: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+07:49:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=9750592, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 00:50:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30646]: 02339OqL008906: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+21:41:17, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=19470583, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 01:00:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30660]: 023MRjPq024050: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+02:32:56, xdelay=00:10:36, mailer=esmtp, pri=7230592, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [172.217.218.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 01:00:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30660]: 023H1exj022946: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+07:59:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=9840592, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 01:00:41 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30660]: 02339OqL008906: to=<otagoHarbour@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=1+21:51:17, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=19560583, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Mar  5 01:07:30 ip-10-0-1-76 sendmail[30700]: 02517Uj6030700: from=www-data, size=342, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202003050107.02517Uj6030700@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, relay=www-data@localhost
Mar  5 01:07:30 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30701]: 02517UA4030701: from=<www-data@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, size=583, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202003050107.02517Uj6030700@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar  5 01:07:30 ip-10-0-1-76 sendmail[30700]: 02517Uj6030700: to=otagoHarbour@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30342, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (02517UA4030701 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar  5 01:09:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sendmail[30846]: 025191nX030846: from=root, size=550, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202003050109.025191nX030846@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=root@localhost
Mar  5 01:09:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30847]: 025191Bc030847: from=<root@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, size=848, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202003050109.025191nX030846@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, bodytype=7BIT, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar  5 01:09:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sendmail[30846]: 025191nX030846: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30550, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (025191Bc030847 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar  5 01:09:01 ip-10-0-1-76 sm-mta[30848]: 025191Bc030847: to=<root@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal>, ctladdr=<root@ip-10-0-1-76.ec2.internal> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31084, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

The following

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep sendmail
```

returns

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
1337/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
 1337/sendmail: MTA:
```

An ISP would not be an issue since I am running the application from a AWS EC2 instance on the cloud.

I noticed that

```
df -i
```

returns

```
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           124432    357 124075    1% /dev
tmpfs          126762    472 126290    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     917504 607710 309794   67% /
tmpfs          126762      1 126761    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          126762      6 126756    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          126762     16 126746    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          126762      4 126758    1% /run/user/1000
```

so it is not an issue with inodes.

```
 ps -e | grep sendmail
```

returns

```
  1337 ?        00:00:08 sendmail-mta
  4109 ?        00:00:00 sendmail-mta
  4320 ?        00:00:00 sendmail-mta
```

The mail just does not show up, even to the spam folder.

Edit:

I also tried

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-76:~$ sendmail otagoharbour@gmail.com
Test
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-76:~$
```

Still no mail shows up in my gmail account.

Comment: Did you try with other mail than gmail?

Comment: Just tried yahoo mail with the same result.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a change that AWS made. I fixed the problem as follows.

1. Installed, and set up Postfix as outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto).
2. Edited AWS EC2
   instance filter to allow SMTP on port 587.
3. Edited /etc/postfix/main.cf to include relayhost = [email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com]:587.
4. sudo postfix reload